# Select with case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure. I have a problem on `EP.Clerepartition` column. I want to select this column based on cases. Where do i need to set my code?

I tried this code and I get an error near to `EP.CleRepartition`

> 'The multipart identifier could not be bound'

Is my query correct or can I do it another way?

```
@PROJET_ID int = NULL,  @RoleID int=NULL

declare @query varchar (250) set @query= (select EP.CleRepartition
from EQUIPE_PROJET EP where EP.Projet_Id=@PROJET_ID AND EP.Role_Id=3
and EP.CleRepartition Is not null ) 

SELECT  U.USR_PRENOM ,U.USR_LOGIN,       EP.CleRepartition=     case
EP.CleRepartition 
      when @RoleID=1 and @requete IS NOT NULL then 100 - @requete 
      when EP.Role_Id=2 and @requete IS NOT NULL then 20
      ELSE NULL      END   
 FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP
 INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR U ON  U.USR_ID = [User_Id]
 INNER JOIN Ref_Role_Eq RE ON RE.Role_Eq_Id = [Role_Id] 
 WHERE (@PROJET_ID IS NULL OR @PROJET_ID = [Projet_Id]) AND EP.Deletion_Date IS NULL
 AND (@RoleID is NULL or [Role_Id] =@RoleID)
```

I expect the output usr name, usr login, role name and cleRepartition.

Comment: `@requete!= NULL` never test NULL this way. use `@requete IS NOT NULL`

Comment: you should post examples of the table you're using. You can use this: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: Hello @Serg it worked for me i am getting the wanted result. But getting also all the records in the table.

Comment: Sure you'll get all the rows, you query has no `WHERE` clause to filter rows after `JOIN`.

Comment: This is the where i have:  WHERE (@PROJET_ID IS NULL OR @PROJET_ID = [Projet_Id]) AND EP.Deletion_Date IS NULL
  AND (@RoleID is NULL or [Role_Id] =@RoleID)
END

Comment: Having the wanted result and all the records with

Comment: Please update the question to show the whole query with `WHERE`

Comment: Thank you so mch @Serg it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this way-

```
SELECT  U.USR_PRENOM ,U.USR_LOGIN,      
CleRepartition=      
CASE
     when @RoleID=1 and @requete IS NOT NULL then 100 - @requete 
     when EP.Role_Id=2 and @requete IS NOT NULL then 20
     ELSE NULL      
END   
FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP   
INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR U ON  U.USR_ID = [User_Id] -- Please define this user id belongs to which table   
INNER JOIN Ref_Role_Eq RE ON RE.Role_Eq_Id = [Role_Id]
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. I am not having an error but not having neither the result.

Comment: Can you please check with the updated script? just changed != NULL to IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Yes it's working with IS NOT NULL. But i am having the result and all the records also. i updated the query on the post

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could see incorrect is how you are building the case. The syntax for this is correct without any sample data I can't really test.

```
declare @query varchar (250) set @query= (select EP.CleRepartition
from EQUIPE_PROJET EP where EP.Projet_Id=@PROJET_ID AND EP.Role_Id=3
and EP.CleRepartition Is not null ) 

  SELECT  U.USR_PRENOM ,U.USR_LOGIN, 
  case 
     when @RoleID=1 and @requete!= NULL then 100 - @requete 
     when EP.Role_Id=2 and @requete != NULL then 20
     ELSE NULL      END as CleRepartition   FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] EP   INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR U ON  U.USR_ID = [User_Id]   INNER JOIN Ref_Role_Eq RE ON
RE.Role_Eq_Id = [Role_Id]  END
```

EDIT:

If you are trying to do a case and bring back the column based on column values it would look more like this:

```
case when **columnFoo=1 then EP.CleRepartition**
     when @RoleID=1 and @requete!= NULL then 100 - @requete 
     when EP.Role_Id=2 and @requete != NULL then 20
     ELSE NULL      END as CleRepartition
```

this would return the value of EP.CleRepartition when columnfoo was equal to 1

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. When i tested it i did not work. i added EP.CleRepartition and i had the same error;

Comment: FROM [EQUIPE_PROJET] XP   INNER JOIN UTILISATEUR U ON U.USR_ID = [XP.User_Id]
INNER JOIN Ref_Role_Eq RE ON
 RE.Role_Eq_Id = [XP.Role_Id]  END

Comment: Try and use a different qualifier for the  EQUIPE_PROJET table and qualify all tables and columns

Comment: Same error : the multipart identifier could not be bound